# Table in Bootstrap Grid System

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```html
<table class="fees-table table-bordered"  data-toggle="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <label>DHL</label>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <label>DHL</label>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <label>Mallory</label>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <label>BOND</label>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <label>CQE/Non</label>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <label>Agave</label>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <label>Fees</label>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>Entry</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>Harbor Maintenance</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>%</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>ISF</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>Merch. Processing</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>%</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>FDA Notice</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>Express Mail</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>Disbursement</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>Mex Honey USDA</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>$</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>Avg 2 Customs Withdrawls</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label></label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>Border Whse</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>$/PLT</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>Mexican Pre-Validation</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>Mexican Customs</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>US Customs</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>Border Drayage</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>Border Warehouse</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>Blocking & Bracing</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>Total</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

My requirement is , i want 2,3,4 columns should be scrollable because i want to add extra columns to that. I want an idea how to do it? using tables or grid system n bootstrap?
Any suggestions please?

Table should be responsive also. Only that 3 columns should be scrollable with that extra added columns?

Comment: So you need some columns to be scrollable?

Comment: yes, just that three columns and when i add another that too.

Comment: Do you also need unscrollable columns?

Comment: Ya i need them.

Answer (score -1):

to make a table responsive make a structure as follows

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
// rest of the code
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: where should i keep that class {.your-class} ?